# Ring homomorphism that maps unity to unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ring homomorphism $f \colon R \to S$ doesn't have to map unity of $R$ to unity of $S$. Is it enough to show that $f$ is onto to know that $f$ maps unity of $R$ to unity of $S$?

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$Yes, because in this case every element of $S$ is of the form $f(r)$ for some $r$.

Therefore
$$
f(r) f(1_{R}) = f(r 1_{R}) = f(r)
$$
(where $1_{R}$ is the unity of $R$) and similarly
$$f(1_{R}) f(r) = f(r),$$
showing that $f(1_{R})$ is the unity for $S$.

This actually proves that if $R$ has a unity, and $f : R \to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, then $S$ has a unity $f(1_{R})$ as well.

Then, of course, there are rings with unity $R, S$ and non-surjective ring homomorphisms $f : R \to S$ which map the unity of $R$ to the unity of $S$. Think of inclusion $\Z \to \Q$. So $f$ being onto is sufficient, but not necessary, for $f$ to map unity to unity.